# Opencart - Upload File Button not working in all browsers

Tags: file-upload, opencart

I have added an OC (v1.5.6) extension ([Customer Order Product Upload](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=1887&filter_search=Customer%20Order%20Product%20Upload&filter_username=hydrowire)) that allows users to drag and drop files in the upload file option.

My problem is that if I click on Upload File to browse my computer for the file it only seems to work in Chrome, Safari & Opera. I have tested it in Firefox & IE and it doesn't work.

I have searched the product.tpl file and found nothing that should cause this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you got weird css translation in your `copu.css` (around line 95)

`transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);`

Which translate `<input type="file" multiple="" name="file" class="fileupload">` this`input` element to 300 pixels to the left thus it no longer overlaps with your `Upload File`

This syntax only works in firefox and ie

So lucky for you that is invalid syntax for webkit browsers (Chrome Opera). so it was not working (and therefore whole thing was working) in chrome, opera etc

I don't know why this line is translating `input` to different place so in my opinion just remove the line but for future if you want this line to work on webkit browsers also then along with above line also add lines with browser specific prefix (`-webkit-`in this case) like this

`-webkit-transform:translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);`

Also note there are prefix for ie and firefox also. but some properties work without prefix also

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks! I just changed the -300 to 0.